# Rewrite values from one pointer to another

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I would like to rewrite values from one pointer to another. I have got two matrixes that used in code and everything well. They are allocated, have the same sizes, and are created in structs.

```
typedef struct{
  int rows;
  int cols;
  int *values;
} matrix;
```

Here is the code how I rewrite them:

```
m1->values = m2->values;
```

This way rewrites them properly, but Valgrind shows:

```
Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
```

Deallocation works until I want to rewrite it. How can I rewrite values without this problem? Is it possible? Heap summary says: ***total heap usage: 8 allocs, 8 frees, 5,240 bytes allocated***

Comment: `m1->values = m2->values;` may be appropriate or fatal, depending on all the other code. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: `m1->values = m2->values;` does not "rewrite the values"; it simply copies the pointer, so now you have *2* pointers to the same thing.  Which would be a problem if you tried to `free` it under each pointer (which I can only assume you are, as you have shared none of the relevant code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `values` is declared as a pointer to `int`. (This means that `values` contains just the address of memory that you must allocate somewhere.)

This means that `m1->values = m2->values;` only copies the memory address that's stored in `values`.

In order to copy, you need something like:

```
#include <string.h>

size_t size = m2->rows * m2->cols * sizeof(int);
m1->values = malloc(size);
memcpy(m1->values, m2->values, size);
```

I assuming you understand that you also need to allocate memory for `m2->values` to begin with.